# Countif Formula to exclude Duplicates

Tags: unique, countif, unique-values

I sought help regarding this once, but I failed to outline my problem.

This time I am happy to share the sheet with dummy data in hope it explains my problem a bit better: [Link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yOkKshfl7xIwH9mrV03IkGhyHfpyRBb8x04ntXlwOik/edit?usp=sharing)

My issue is the following:

In column E I am counting the number of opportunities for a rep (listed in column A). The data I am considering is in a separate sheet named "Pipeline".
I do this with the countif formula and I use additional criteria to filter on date as well. My dates for february are in B4 and G4, because I only want to see opportunities in February.

My formula looks like this:

=countIFS(Pipeline!$A:$A,$A7,Pipeline!$F:$F,">="&$B$4,Pipeline!$F:$F,"<="&$G$4)

This works perfectly fine. However, sometimes I have two opportunities in my pipeline sheet with the same name (these are split opportunities). If an opportunity has the same name it should be counted only once. I can't seem to find an easy way to update my countif formula.

In the dummy sheet I shared above, you can see that Peter has two "New - CC Tech" opportunities. I want this to count as one opportunity. Everything I googled so far suggests using rather complex formulas, which is not so easy as I have multiple criteria in the formula that I need to filter my results (such as name of the rep and dates). Please feel free to suggest a solution within the sheet above and play around with it.

I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Access is denied to your spreadsheet. Please give access.

Comment: Can you request access? I haven’t received an access request

Comment: @MikeSteelson I have granted you access to the sheet. Were you able to take a look at it?

Comment: Can you specify the criteria for what you call duplicates? For example columns A, B and F

Comment: @MikeSteelson Sorry, Mike, I forgot to mention that. The criteria would be in column B. That's the name of the opportunity and when an opportunity has the same name, then it's a duplicate. So that would be my unique identifier

Comment: ok, so try the second formula hereafter and let me know if it is ok for you!

Comment: @MikeSteelson I tried the second formula in cell E9 on the main tab and it's showing the result "2". Which is correct... I don't understand the formula one bit but it looks like it's working :) Thank you so much

Comment: @MikeSteelson Could you help me out one more time? If you access the sheet again, you will see that I am trying to do the same as before but I am using the criteria from column J instead of column A. That's the only thing that changed but i can't seem to figure out how to update the formula... As you can see it shows #VALUE for but the expected result should be 1.

Comment: done, let me know if it is ok! I have replace `Pipeline!A$2:B` by `Pipeline!J$2:J,Pipeline!B$2:B`, so the first column (Col1) will be J instead of A.

Comment: @MikeSteelson Thank you so much for your speedy help!! I will accept the answer now. Sorry for not having done it before.

Comment: @MikeSteelson One more thing that I noticed it that the formula returns N/A instead instead of 0 when there is no result, which is a little weird. But I can build an enclosing formula for that. Thanks a ton!

Comment: yes, put `=iferror(____________________,0)` I apologize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ('unique' based on A,B and F)

```
=query(unique({Pipeline!A:B,Pipeline!F:F}),"select count(Col1) where Col1='"&A7&"' and Col3>=DATE'"&TEXT($B$4,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and Col3<=DATE'"&TEXT($G$4,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' label count(Col1) '' ")
```

or, if you consider that the date could be different between two lines ('unique' based only on A and B, the date could be different but within the limits)

```
=query(unique({Pipeline!A$2:B,arrayformula((Pipeline!F$2:F>=$B$4)*(Pipeline!F$2:F<=$G$4))}),"select count(Col1) where Col1='"&A7&"' and Col3>0 label count(Col1) '' ")
```

In this second formula, we construct a matrix with A, B and 0/1 (which is the result of the question: is F within limits), then we apply unique and we query when Col3 is equal to 1 and Col1 the name we are looking for

Comment: Hey Mike! Still working with your formula and it's going really well. I am now trying to add a new condition to the sheet, but I am struggling a little bit. The formula should remain the same I just want to say it "please do this only with all A and B tiers only" or basically "disregard any C tier". I have added the Tiers to sheet as well. I tried something in Cell E8 but it's showing me an error... Can you help?

Comment: In E7 `=iferror(query(unique({Pipeline!K$2:K,Pipeline!B$2:B,arrayformula((Pipeline!G$2:G>=$B$4)*(Pipeline!G$2:G<=$G$4)),Pipeline!D$2:D}),"select count(Col1) where Col1='"&$A7&"' and Col3>0 and Col4<>'C' label count(Col1) '' "),0)` Take a look inside the file! Glad to hear you once more.

Comment: I am happy to hear you once again too! Thank you so much for the prompt help. This is excluding tier C, correct?